# Is there a way to hide a list of channels with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i've been writing a bot for one of my friends servers and i can seem to get it working. I need a way to hide multiple channels. I have already written a function to give me all the channels i need to hide in an array. I need a function that when called it will iterate over the items in my array it will remove the `read_messages` permission from a specified user that my function also supplies.

```
# expected input
hide(channels_to_hide, user)
```

Expected output: All channels listed in `channels_to_hide` are hidden from `user`.

I have tried to use `await channel.set_permissions()` but cant seem to get that to work, and the docs seem a bit spacey when hiding the channels.
Also im using the discord.py rewrite version.

Thanks,
*Soupy*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider a role which will hide all the given channels.
You can get the role and add it like this, this is to executed inside [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if message.author.id != bot.user.id:
        return # not to take reactions from message not made by the bot itself
    
    role = 'hide' # you can also use a list of roles 
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)

    user = await bot.fetch_user(payload.user_id)
    name = guild.get_member_named(user.name)
    await name.add_roles(role)
```

Another way to add roles is like this

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role to add name")
user = ctx.message.author
await user.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: How would I take this role and hide the actual channel though? Is there a sort of hide channel from role command? And if so how would I use it in the context of your example above?

Comment: You would have to pre-configure the role, the easiest way is using the GUI (the discord app itself)